# copy file to filename with datetime works in bash but not in makefile

Tags: make

The following works in a bash shell

```
cp abc.tex "abc-$(date +"%Y-%m-%-d-%H-%M-%S").tex"
```

but not in a makefile. How do I fix it?

Here's the makefile:

```
b:
    cp abc.tex "abc-$(date +"%Y-%m-%-d-%H-%M-%S").tex"
```

When I do "make b", bash says:

```
cp abc.tex "abc-.tex"
```

Comment: What does your Makefile look like, how do you invoke `make` exactly, and in what particular way does your command not work?

Comment: I've added a makefile and also how bash respond when I execute make.

Comment: you should double the `$` if you want it to be passed to the shell: `abc-$$(date...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Makefile, `$(...)` denotes the expansion of a multi-character `make` variable.  You don't have a `make` variable called `date +"%Y-%m-%-d-%H-%M-%S"`, so it is replace by an empty string.

To let the shell that `make` uses execute `$(...)` as a command substitution, write it as `$$(...)`:

```
b:
        cp abc.tex "abc-$$(date +"%Y-%m-%-d-%H-%M-%S").tex"
```

The GNU `make` variant of `make` also has `$(shell ...)` which works in a similar way as a command substitution in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for the `$(shell ...)` macro.

```
b:
    cp abc.tex "abc-$(shell date +"%Y-%m-%-d-%H-%M-%S").tex"
```

This generates the following output

```
> make b
cp abc.tex "abc-2021-10-21-16-54-02.tex"
```